# Getting error A RenderFlex overflowed by 337 pixels on the right. Also getting Image error [FLUTTER]

Tags: flutter, dart

Actually I am trying to create a alert dialog with a icon in the title followed by the the heading the problem is whem i am using a image.network on a image whose size is 192x192 px it is working file but when I am using a image.asset on a image which has same size (192x192 px) then it gives me the error that **A RenderFlex overflowed by 337 pixels on the right.** I tried many different images with different sizes but nothing works.

Here is the code:

```
showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (build) {
    return AlertDialog(
      title: Row(children: [
        Image.asset(
          'assets/image.png',
          height: 50,
          width: 50,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
        ),
        Text('  Alert Dialog Title.')
      ]),
      content: Text("Are You Sure Want To Proceed?"),
      actions: <Widget>[
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("YES"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
        ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("CANCEL"),
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ],
    );
```

Also Getting the Image.asset error My image path and pubspec.yaml file is correct i checked it twice.

```
======== Exception caught by image resource service ================================================
The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/recipedia.png.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      PlatformAssetBundle.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:288:7)
#1      AssetBundleImageProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:731:35)
#2      AssetBundleImageProvider.loadBuffer (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:695:14)
#3      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:513:13)
#4      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:384:22)
#5      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:511:81)
#6      ScrollAwareImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey (package:flutter/src/widgets/scroll_aware_image_provider.dart:106:19)
#7      ImageProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:358:9)
#8      ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:473:24)
#9      SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:41:35)
#10     ImageProvider._createErrorHandlerAndKey (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:470:9)
#11     ImageProvider.resolve (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:355:5)
#12     _ImageState._resolveImage (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1115:16)
#13     _ImageState.didChangeDependencies (package:flutter/src/widgets/image.dart:1065:5)
#14     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5036:11)
#15     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4853:5)
#16     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#17     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
#18     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6447:32)
...     Normal element mounting (13 frames)
#31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#32     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
#33     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6447:32)
...     Normal element mounting (288 frames)
#321    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3863:16)
#322    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6435:36)
#323    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3592:18)
#324    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5964:32)
#325    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6460:17)
#326    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#327    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#328    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#329    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#330    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5082:5)
#331    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#332    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#333    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#334    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5228:5)
#335    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#336    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#337    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#338    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5228:5)
#339    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:107:11)
#340    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#341    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6307:14)
#342    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#343    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#344    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#345    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#346    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5082:5)
#347    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#348    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6307:14)
#349    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#350    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6307:14)
#351    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#352    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#353    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#354    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5228:5)
#355    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3570:15)
#356    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4904:16)
#357    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5050:11)
#358    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4604:5)
#359    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2667:19)
#360    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#361    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:378:5)
#362    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1175:15)
#363    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1104:9)
#364    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1015:5)
#365    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:148:13)
#366    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:318:5)
#367    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:115:31)
Image provider: ExactAssetImage(name: "assets/recipedia.png", scale: 1.0, bundle: null)
Image key: AssetBundleImageKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#cbf2c(), name: "assets/recipedia.png", scale: 1.0)
====================================================================================================
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your text widget.

```dart
        showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (build) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Row(children: [
              Image.asset(
                'assets/images/image.jpeg',
                height: 50,
                width: 50,
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),

              // wrap your long text in [Flexible] and give the Text widget [overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis]
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  'Getting error A RenderFlex overflowed by 337 pixels on the right. ',
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 2,
                ),
              ),
            ]),
            content: Text(
                "A RenderFlex overflowed by 337 pixels on the right. I tried many different images with different sizes but nothing works. Are You Sure Want To Proceed?"),
            actions: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("YES"),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text("CANCEL"),
                onPressed: () {},
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I am getting this error `The following assertion was thrown resolving an image codec:
Unable to load asset: assets/recipedia.png.` This thing I don't understand is I am giving the correct path of the image and my pubspec file is correct because it load other images. I don't know what the problem?

Comment: try to re-run flutter or ```flutter clean && flutter pub get```